# How do I leverage Marionette to rerender a nested CompositeView after a child's model is destroyed?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I thought Marionette would handle removing the views of destroyed models automatically but it's not working in my situation. I have a CompositeView which displays a collection of movies. Each movie has a list of actors. When I click "Delete Movie" it should delete all the associated actors and update the view with that particular movie which was removed. Currently, my application destroys the models but the view isn't updated. If I refresh the page, the movie and associated actors are gone so I know it's destroying the models, just not the views the moment it is clicked. How can I get Marionette to handle this?

Relevant controller code:

```
 /* in my list_controller.js */

 MovieApp.module("ActorsApp.List", function(List, MovieApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
  List.Controller = {

    listActors: function(){
      var actors = MovieApp.request("actor:entities");
      var movies = new Backbone.Collection;
      var allMovies= MovieApp.request("movie:entities");

      actors.each(function(actor) {
        movieId = actor.get("movieId");

        if (!movies.get(movieId) ){

          //console.log("Movie not found. Adding to list list.");
          movie = allMovies.get(movieId);

          selectedActors = actors.where({ movieId: movieId });

          //console.log("Selected Actors: ", selectedActors);
          movie.actors=selectedActors;

          movies.add(allMovies.get(movieId));

        }
        else {
          console.log("Movie found in list. Skipping.")

        }

      });

      var moviesListView = new List.Movies({
        collection: movies
      });

      moviesListView.on("itemview:actor:new", function(childView, model){
        MovieApp.ActorsApp.New.Controller.newActor(model);
      });

      moviesListView.on("itemview:itemview:actor:show", function(childView, model){
        MovieApp.ActorsApp.Show.Controller.showActor(model);
      });

      moviesListView.on("itemview:movie:show", function(childView, model){
        MovieApp.MoviesApp.Show.Controller.showMovie(model);
      });

      moviesListView.on("itemview:movie:delete", function(childView, model){

        childView.children.each(function(child){
          child.model.destroy();
        });

        // This removes a model from the moviesListView collection
        this.collection.remove(childView.model);  

        this.render();

      });

      moviesListView.on("itemview:itemview:actor:delete", function(childView, model){
        model.model.destroy();
      });

      moviesListView.on("movie:list", function(){
        MovieApp.MoviesApp.List.Controller.listMovies();
      });

      MovieApp.mainRegion.show(moviesListView);

    }


  }
});
```

Here is my view code:

```
List.Movie = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: "#actor-movie-list-item",
    itemView: List.Actor,
    initialize: function(){

       console.log("Actors: ", this.model.actors);

        actors = this.model.actors;

        this.collection = actors;

        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(actors);

    },

    events: {
        "click a.js-remove-movie" : "deleteClicked"
    },

    deleteClicked: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.trigger("movie:delete", this.model);
    },

    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
        var container;

        container = this.$('.recipe-list');
        container.append(itemView.el);
    },


    onRender: function() {
        if(_.isUndefined(this.collection)){
            this.$("ul:first").remove();

        }
        console.log("Movie render called.");
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't entirely see what you're trying to achieve, however if you want to update the views after destroying a model try this:

```
recipesListView.on("itemview:movie:delete", function(childView){
    // This removes a model from the recipesListView collection
    this.collection.remove(childView.model);  
});
```

This assumes that your recipesListView is either a collection- or a compositeView. 
Also check: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

I also created a fiddle to demonstrate using a compositeView and deleting an item through events: http://jsfiddle.net/Cardiff/JEx6Y/

**If above doesn't help you out, can you explain:**
- In the list.view, what's the `this.model.actors`?
- How are your views structured (nesting of view types)
- How is your data defined in models and collections?

Comment: Thank you, Wilbert. This definitely is what worked to update the view but when I reload the page, the deleted item returns. I added your line to what I had and it seems to work now and actually destroys the models but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

     childView.children.each(function(child){
          child.model.destroy();
        });

Comment: I've updated the original question to include my controller code. I'm still learning so I think I might not be handling the relationships correctly. Actor models store a movieId to pull them into the list. This could be done cleaner so I am open to suggestions. To answer your question about this.model.actors, I am trying to store the associated actors in the movie model. This doesn't seem like the correct way to do it but everything appears to be working now I just wish I knew the correct way to do it.

Comment: Essentially what you want to do is define relationships between models. Take a look at this: http://backbonerelational.org/

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! I think Backbone-relational will handle everything I would need. I will mark this as the accepted answer.